# Determining a function is absolutely integrable over the real line

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I'm having a hard time understanding *absolutely integrable functions* and determining them. Can you please explain briefly what is this *absolutley integrable over the real line* and also how to determine whether a function is. ie. How to determine this?
$$\frac{sin(x^2)}{1+x^2}$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is absolutely integrable, any $g$ with $|g| \le f$ is also. Now compare your $g$ to $f$ with $f(x) = (1+x^2)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An [absolutely integrable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_integrable_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20absolutely%20integrable,both%20and%20must%20be%20finite.) is a function whose absolute value is integrable.

To see that your function is absolutely integrable, we need to see if its absolute value is integrable over the real line:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)}{1+x^2}\right|dx\overset * = 2\int_{0}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)}{1+x^2}\right|dx \le 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx}_{(1)} + 2\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx}_{(2)}$$
Since both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are convergent, the given integral is convergent as well.

**Explanation:**

$(*)$: Function is even

$(1)$: Used $\sin(x^2) \le x^2$.

$(2)$: Used $\sin(x^2)\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is even, so you just need proving that the integral
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)dx}{1+x^2}$$
is absolutely convergent.

For this, observe that

$$(\forall x\ge 1)\; |\frac{\sin(x^2)}{1+x^2}|\le \frac{1}{x^2}$$

and that

$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
is convergent.
Now, use the Comparison criterion for positive functions.